# Rails 3.1.3 getting error in staging server while compiling assets using compass+sussy+haml+scss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, compass-sass

My application is working fine in development environment with compass and sussy for haml and scss and the Gemfile configuration for the aplication is -: [Gist for Gemfile](https://gist.github.com/2003755)

and my application.rb settings looks like this -:

```
if defined?(Sass)
 config.sass.load_paths << "#{Gem.loaded_specs['compass'].full_gem_path}/frameworks/compass/stylesheets"
 config.sass.load_paths << "#{Gem.loaded_specs['compass'].full_gem_path}/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets" 
 config.sass.load_paths << "#{Gem.loaded_specs['compass-susy-plugin'].full_gem_path}/sass"
end
 config.assets.precompile << /(^[^_]|\/[^_])[^\/]*/
```

But when i deploy my application to the server. Which is in **staging** environment . Always throws me error -:

```
Error compiling asset application.css:
    Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$base-font-size".
    (in /var/www/App-staging/releases/20120405100127/app/assets/stylesheets/_mobile-first.scss)
    Served asset /application.css - 500 Internal Server Error
```

And if i try the some hacks and patches provided gives me error -:

```
Compiled application.css  
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 419ms

ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3/.
Load path: Sass::Rails::Importer
```

So can is this is the issue with Compass and rails version? Ans is there any permanent solution to get rid of this or any working configuration for staging and production environment .
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you import the SASS file using

```
"import _mobile-first";
```

In addition, in rails 3.1, the correct filename would be

```
mobile_first.css.erb.scss
```

*note: You don't need the leading underscore.*

This will allow you to import the file using the scss import, while still using erb for inserting assets using the asset path helper.

```
<%= asset_path 'twitter.png' %>
```

You are using an older version of the compass gem. Upgrade to 0.12.1.

If that still does not work, try removing these lines from application.rb

```
if defined?(Sass)
 config.sass.load_paths << "#{Gem.loaded_specs['compass'].full_gem_path}/frameworks/compass/stylesheets"
 config.sass.load_paths << "#{Gem.loaded_specs['compass'].full_gem_path}/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets" 
 config.sass.load_paths << "#{Gem.loaded_specs['compass-susy-plugin'].full_gem_path}/sass"
end
```

You don't need them. The app will run fine without them. I've never needed to add those lines to application.rb

If that still does not work also remove the following line and try it.

```
 config.assets.precompile << /(^[^_]|\/[^_])[^\/]*/
```

If this still doesn't work, can you post the contents of mobile_first.scss as well as application.scss?

Comment: You are also using an older gem version of compass. Try upgrading to the latest

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your deploy scripts are calling assets:precompile with the RAILS_ENV set to staging like so:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=staging
```

Can you run the above command on your development machine?

Comment: No its gave the error
    undefined method `sass' for #           <Rails::Application::Configuration:0xa05f348>